# Using XML to add a custom button on Outlook 2013's Meeting Request Ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to add a button to Outlook's 'Respond' meeting request ribbon, but it's not showing.

[image]

I've downloaded both the Office 2010 and 2013 [MSOID identifiers files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627) from Microsoft, but I still can't seem to get it working.

Here are some XML combinations I've tried:

```
<tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabReadMessage">
        <group idMso="GroupRespond">
          <menu idMso="MenuAcceptInvitation">
            <button id="MyButtonAttachments"
                    label="MyButtonAttachments"
                    imageMso="HappyFace"
                    onAction="OnMyButtonClick" />
          </menu>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
```

I also tried adding another group which doesn't show either:

```
<contextualTabs>
      <tabSet idMso="TabSetAppointment">
        <tab idMso="TabAppointment">
          <group label="MyGroup1" id="MyAttachmentGroup">
            <button id="MyButtonAttachments1"
                    size="large"
                    label="MyButtonAttachments"
                    imageMso="HappyFace"
                    onAction="OnMyButtonClick" />
          </group>
        </tab>
      </tabSet>
    </contextualTabs>
```

Comment: I don't have 2010 here but when I try your code in 2007 with this settings - [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619(v=vs.100).aspx)
it says - 
`Failed to find Office control by ID`
`ID: TabReadMessage`

- are you sure you use the correct name? Otherwise it seems you're doing it correctly

Comment: Actually thanks alot for the link to Interface Errors, I'm sure that'll point me in the right direction at least. I'll give it a try when I'm back at work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Outlook doesn't want me adding anything to their existing interface groups (in this case `idMso="GroupRespond"`). Oh well.

[image]